# Send jQuery value to PHP

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I'm trying to pass 'value' to the 'prova.php' page in order to make a mysql query dynamicly. But this is not working.. What should I add?   All the stuff under the php open tag have to be dynamic: no page load. Here is my prova.php file's code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

      <div id="single">
        <input type="text" value="test test"/><br /> 
    </div>
    <p></p>

    <div id="fo">focusout fire</div>
    <div id="b">blur fire</div>

    <script>

    var fo = 0, b = 0;
    $("#single").focusout(function(e) {
      fo++;
      $("#fo")
        .text("focusout fired: " + fo + "x");
        var value = (e.target.value );
        alert( value );

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "prova.php",
      data: { temp: value }
    })
     /*$.ajax({
            url: 'prova.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data : "temp = 100",
            success: function(data) {
            alert('Load was performed.');
             }  
        });*/
    })

    </script>
    <?php
    $link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
    if (!$link) {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    echo 'Connected successfully';
    mysql_select_db("test");
    //if(isset($_POST['id']))
    $value=$_POST['temp'];
    echo $_POST['temp'];
    $sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM articles WHERE id='$value'");
    if(!$sql)
    echo"ERROR: Invalid Query!";
    $row=mysql_fetch_array($sql);
    $articleText=$row["text"];
    echo$articleText;

    ?>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I've already searched for it using get and post apis of jquery but with no results. I think that I should add more stuff under ajax but I don't know what! The php code should be executed under ajax I think but I'm not very confidential with ajax and jquery: I'm using them for the first time.

Comment: the other thing you can add in ajax is success function that will tell you the status of your result

Comment: You're not doing anything with the value returned from the ajax call.  It might be working, but you're not going to see it.  If you use firebug for firefox or the developer tools in safari/chrome, you can see the XHR request in the "Net" view and observe if the ajax call works at least.

Comment: I would avoid value as the name of the variable, just in case. Have you watched the request/response cycle of the AJAX request in Firebug or some other tool? You'll get a lot of feedback.

Comment: You should not use `mysql_query` in new applications because it's very easy to use it incorrectly. You have a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/php) in this example. New applications should use `mysqli` or PDO to avoid this.

Comment: @tadman my prb is not ' SQL injection bug' :)

Comment: Your problem is you have a SQL injection bug. You're taking a `$_POST` variable and jamming it directly into your query. This is how your site can be completely destroyed using an [automatic SQL injection exploit tool](http://sqlmap.org/). Don't brush this off as not a concern.

Answer (score 0):

First of all the parameter you send is wrong. You have to send a javascript object format (key:value pairs):

```
 $.post("prova.php" ,{
    temp: 100
},function(data){   
 //data "echo"-ed from script                       
});
```

Server-side:

```
$data=$_POST['temp'];
//do your stuff
echo 'done';
```

Comment: I suggest in php part to do not access the POST data directly without checking - if exists :)

Comment: Using JSON would be much better idea for sending data.

Comment: @ilia it's okay to send tat like this way. if you have 1-2 properties. but for large collection of data JSON is more appropriate as you way. main problem is that he didn't check for existence of this key in $_POST array :)

Comment: I am trying to provide a simple example on the XHR request. If I bloat the code with filtering and checks and try catch-es he might not get the point. One thing at a time..

Comment: @radashk my question is my problem.
What should I do to make a html input filed dynamic using jquery ? I have a input field where I add an ID. After that the ID have to be searched in a database making a query. If the query is successful the Text filed on the database should be loaded.

Comment: I've showed you the ajax request and response. Check the firebug console if you have any errors and post them back here.

Comment: @radashk I've installed firebug but I don't know how to use it :(